# Como guardar el response JSON de FETCH en un atributo de una clase?

Tags: javascript, php5, fetch, promesas, async-await

Tengo un inconveniente al querer guardar los datos que recibo por fetch(JSON) en un atributo de una clase;
Lo paso a consola y lo único que me aparece es una Promesa;

Aquí el código;
Estoy diseñando un CRUD con php y javascript vanilla;

```js
export default class Model {
  constructor() {
    this.dataJSON = getData();
  }

  setController(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  async getData() {
    const response = await fetch('../php/get-data.php');
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    return responseJSON;
  }

  
}
```

Comment: [Mira este ejemplo](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/#2-fetching-json) - Cuando tu regresas responseJson en la función asíncrona, todavía es una promesa. Creo que deberías encapsular todo en una Promise, o añadirle un await en el construtor.

Comment: No se le puede añadir un await a un constructor ya que este devuelve un Objeto, Estuve leendo y vi que toda funcion con la palabra async devuelve una promesa, Asi que intente hacerlo de esta manera y tampoco funciona ` export default class Model {
  constructor() {
    this.dataJSON = this.getData();
  }


  getData() {
    let responseJSON = null;
    fetch('../php/get-data.php')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        responseJSON = data;
      });

    return responseJSON;
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haría de manera que el constructor inicialice la propiedad con una variable temporal (no hay manera de obtener los datos de manera instantánea), invoque la función y esta ultima modifique el objeto cuando el pedido se complete. Algo así:

```js
export default class Model {
  constructor() {
    this.dataJSON = "fetching";
    this.getData();
  }

  setController(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  async getData() {
    const response = await fetch('../php/get-data.php');
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    this.dataJSON = responseJSON;
  }


}
```

Ejemplo con el API de la estación espacial internacional:

```js
class Model {
  constructor() {
    this.dataJSON = "fetching";
    this.getData();
  }

  setController(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  async getData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites');
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    this.dataJSON = responseJSON;
    console.log("Llegó la info!");
  }


}

const satelite = new Model();
console.log(satelite);
console.log("Esperando a que pasen 3 segundos para asegurar que la información llegó.");
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(satelite)
}, 3000);
```

Comment: No se si lo ejecutaste pero el valor del atributo this.dataJSON sigue siendo "fetching"

Comment: No puedo ejecutarlo de la misma manera que tu, no tengo acceso a `'../php/get-data.php'`. Sin embargo puedo hacerte un ejemplo.

Comment: Puedes crear un archivo test.json con este JSON `[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "nameTest",
    "lastname": "lastnameTest",
    "age": "20",
    "position": "developer",
    "birthday": "12-12-2000"
  }
]` , y hacer el fetch a ese archivo

Comment: Te lo hice con el API de la Estación Espacial, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Ya entendí cual fue problema, Esque yo llamaba a console.log() al mismo tiempo que ejecutiva el fetch y como javascript es asíncrono la mejor opcion que le veo es trabajar todas las funciones que interactúen con fetch como función async, Me di cuenta gracias al SetTimeOut de tu codigo jejej, De todas formas Gracias

Comment: Con mucho gusto, la idea del `setTimeout` era representar la asincronía, entonces parece ser que funcionó!